# how can i get the desktop full address of user?

Tags: c#

i want to get the full address of user programatically  using c# how can i do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx)

Passing in Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory

Comment: Depending on what you're looking for there's also the virtual directory Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop